# Numpy Image Array Replace specific color with 1, other colors with 0

Tags: python, numpy

I have to Encode an Image for Semantic Segmentation. The Input Image is of shape (128, 256, 3) with 128 x 256 RGB Values. I want an Output Shape of (128, 256) where every 1 represent, that the pixel matched the given Color and 0 represents, that another RGB Value was present.

[[20, 20, 20], [30, 30, 30], [40, 40, 40]] with the Filter [20,20,20] should result in [1, 0, 0]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Optimally This Method should be feasible to apply to an array of shape (16, 128, 256, 3) with 16 pictures in it, applying the filter to every picture.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, your example, the matrix `[[20, 20, 20], [30, 30, 30], [40, 40, 40]]` is 2D, so the filter should be 20 only and the result will be `[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`, is it correct?

Comment: The Matrix in the Question is just an example. The Natrix in my Code is of shape (16, 128, 256, 3) or (8, 128, 1256, 3) based on my batch_size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.where` for one image:

```
filter_pixel = np.array([20, 20, 20])
image = np.array([[[20, 20, 20], [30, 30, 30], [40, 40, 40]],
                  [[20, 10, 20], [20, 20, 20], [40, 40, 40]]])

new_image = np.where(np.all(image == filter_pixel, axis=2), 1,0)
print(new_image)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]]
```

edit, for a number of images:

```
filter_pixels = np.array([[20, 20, 20], [30, 30, 30]])
filter_pixels = filter_pixels[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
images = np.array([[[[20, 20, 20], [30, 30, 30], [40, 40, 40]],
                    [[20, 10, 20], [20, 20, 20], [40, 40, 40]]],
                  [[[20, 20, 20], [30, 30, 30], [40, 40, 40]],
                   [[20, 10, 30], [20, 20, 20], [30, 30, 30]]]])

new_images = np.where(np.all(images == filter_pixels, axis=3), 1, 0)

print(new_images)
```

Output:

```
[[[1 0 0]
  [0 1 0]]

 [[0 1 0]
  [0 0 1]]]
```

Comment: The Problem with this approach is that it returns 1 if one element matches the filter. e.g. image = np.array([[20, 20, 20], [20, 30, 30], [40, 40, 40]]) would result in [1, 1, 0] which is not what i want

Comment: Yea , you are right. Just edited to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out with your approach. I had to use axis=3 since my array has one dimension more than your test array, but it works just fine and is computationally fast. Thanks a Lot!

Comment: I added the complete answer for you question, it now works for a number of images.

Comment: Great, thank you. I am now stuck with decoding the images after my network made a prediction. So now i Want to come from shape(16, 128, 256, 12) to shape (16, 128, 256, 3), where the pixel take the color value of the maximum number from the 12 values in the output array. I dont manage to get that right. Maybe you can help again

Comment: Just to clarify, let's say you have this array in last dimension: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].
So you want to put there the color [12,12,12] ?

Comment: The Array I have after succesfully encoding it always consists of one one and the rest zeros. So for example the output could be [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. This would be interpreted as class 0 (from 12). Now i want to replace these classes with the respective rgb values again, so if class 0 corrosponds to RBG [80, 80, 80] i want to insert that into the array changing its shape from (16, 128, 256, 12) to (16, 128, 256, 3) again. The output then should match the before existing array which I encoded